# Finding the value of $p$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, economics, utility

I need some help with this question:

Consider an individual who possesses the Bernoulli utility function of $u(x)=\dfrac{x^{1-\gamma }}{1-\gamma }$ where $\gamma>0$, $\gamma \neq 1$. Who maintains an initial level of wealth $W$. Suppose that she is considering a lottery where she wins or losses $x$ with equal probability. Let $p$ be the amount the agent is just willing to pay to avoid the lottery. Find this value, and show that it is decreasing in wealth.

My work:

[image]

Let $W-p$ denote certainty equivalent.

So, $u(W-p)= \dfrac{1}{2}u(W-x)+\dfrac{1}{2}u(W+x)$

$\Rightarrow  \dfrac{(W-p)^{1-\gamma }}{1-\gamma}= \dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{(W-x)^{1-\gamma}}{1-\gamma}+\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{(W+x)^{1-\gamma}}{1-\gamma}$

After doing some algebraic manipulations, I am left with this equation:

$log(W-p)=\dfrac{-2log(2)+log(W-x)+log(W+x)}{1-\gamma}$

From here how do I find $p$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an equation of the form

$$ \log(W - p) = \frac{a\log b  + c\log d + e\log f}{g}$$

then you should solve this equation for $p$ by getting rid of the $\log$s. The easiest way to do this is boil the RHS down to one $\log$ by combining terms using the rules $p\log q$ = $\log (q^p)$ and $\log p + \log q$ = $log (pq)$. Hence

$$ \log(W - p) = \frac1{g} \left(\log (b^a d^c f^e)\right) = \log \left(\left( b^a d^c f^e \right)^{1/g}\right) $$

You can solve this by taking exponents of both sides, which eliminates the $\log$s.

However, you don't need to do this. Starting with your equation

$$\frac{(W-p)^{1-\gamma }}{1-\gamma}= \frac{1}{2}\frac{(W-x)^{1-\gamma}}{1-\gamma}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{(W+x)^{1-\gamma}}{1-\gamma}$$

first cancel through the common fractions

$$(W-p)^{1-\gamma } = \frac{1}{2}\left((W-x)^{1-\gamma}+(W+x)^{1-\gamma}\right)$$

then take raise each side to the power $\dfrac1{1-\gamma}$, leaving $W-p$ on the left (the expression on the right doesn't simplify unfortunately). You can then do a simple rearrangement to find $p$.

---

PS your "after some more algebraic calculations" looks wrong to me. I don't see how you get to your final equation. Did you try to put $\log(a+b)=\log a + \log b$ somewhere?

Comment: Yes I used $log(ab)=loga+logb$ in the process.

Comment: @user36829 it's $\log(ab)=\log a + \log b$. In general $\log(a+b) \neq \log a + \log b$. In any case I don't think actually need to take logs.

Comment: You almost tricked me there for a moment.

Comment: :) yeah sorry I could see after your comment that you misinterpreted my last line

Comment: After following your suggestions I'm left with this: $p = W - \frac{(W-x)^{1-\gamma}+(W+x)^{1-\gamma})^\frac{1}{1-\gamma }}{2^{\frac{1}{1-\gamma }}}$. It is not clear to me how $p$ is decreasing in wealth.

Comment: @user36829 It's a nasty expression alright! My first thought is to try taking a factor of $W$ out of the RHS. So the RHS ends up being $W(1-\mathrm{something})$ Note that you can divide through each of the $(W\pm x)$ terms by $W$: don't just leave $W$ on the denominator.

Comment: @user36829 Also, and please don't take this the wrong way, I think I've tried hard to answer your original question "From here how do I find p" (explaining logs, then explaining that logs aren't the issue), and hopefully I've helped, altho of course it's possible I've made an error somewhere. You can accept my answer or not depending on whether you think it's satisfied your question, but it's really quite hard to take on another q in comments. I think asking another question showing your new working to get $p$ as a function of $W$ then asking how this is a decreasing function is appropriate.